# IllegalStateException when reading InputStream

Tags: android, inputstream, illegalstateexception

I'm using this function in an Android app to download a file from an URL:

```
public static boolean downloadFile(URL url, File file) throws IOException {

    if(!file.getParentFile().exists() && !file.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
        return false;
    }

    File temp = File.createTempFile("file_", ".temp", file.getParentFile());
    temp.deleteOnExit();

    InputStream input = url.openStream();
    try {

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(temp);

        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) { output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); }
        }
        finally { output.close(); }
    }
    finally { input.close(); }

    return temp.renameTo(file);
}
```

I received a few crash reports reporting an IllegalStateException, as you can see on this stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
>       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:174)
>       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$2.read(HttpEngine.java:1212)
>       at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:396)
>       at com.egosventures.stable360.core.utils.Utils.downloadFile(Utils.java:257)

Is there anything to worry about in my code, or it this exception happening only because my user lost his internet access (I want to know if catching the exception and fail gracefully is the best I can do)?

Comment: `File.createTempFile()` You should not create the file already. The only thing you need is a File object with the right path. The file will be created by new FileOutputStream().

Comment: Why? I want to be sure that the file has been downloaded successfully before renaming it to the final destination. The function causing the error is the read, not the write, so  can't see why the use of a temp file would be the cause of my problem.

Comment: I did not say that you should not use a temp file. What i said is that you should not create it twice. Only using new FileOutputStream is enough.

Comment: Oh I see. Well that won't cause any problem, and there's no (out of the box) alternative to createTempFile.

Comment: No. You do not need an alternative as you should not create the file there. You only should create the File object with the right path.